# PageTabViewStyle displays List, not Carousel

Tags: ios, arrays, swiftui

I'm building the step-by-step view for a recipe app. Right now, I’m using `PageTabViewStyle` where each step gets it’s own view; at the moment it's not properly working because every step (expect the first, see GIF) gets returned in this list and swiping left or right is not possible. Has anyone experienced the same? Is there a limit of pages for the TabViewStyle?

[CurrentUIGIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPAXF.gif)

My data file:

```
struct Recipe: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var directions: [String]
}

let recipesData: [Recipe] = [
    Recipe(
        directions: [
            "Gather all ingredients on your countertop. Peas, onions, mineral water, walnuts, almond   butter, olive oil, parsley and mint.",
            "Make the pesto by washing the parsley and mint. Remove the leaves from the stems and set aside.",
            "Peel the two onions and roughly chop them.",
        ]
    )
]
```

My pageTabView View:

```
struct DirectionsView: View {
    var recipe: Recipe

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(recipe.directions, id: \.self) { item in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(item)
                }
            }.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        }
    }
}

struct DirectionsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DirectionsView(recipe: recipesData[0])
    }
}
```

Comment: Having 2 `NavigationView`s can be buggy. The only way to help you is if you provide a minimal, reproducible product. Something we can copy and paste and see the code for the behavior.

Comment: @loremipsum thank you for the recommendation. I edited the code so it's easily reproducible. In this new minimal product, there is no NavigationView and the bug still shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach `.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())` to `TabView` (instead of `ForEach`):

```
struct DirectionsView: View {
    var recipe: Recipe

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(recipe.directions, id: \.self) { item in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
    }
}
```